# What is the R code for making a Kaplan Meier plot for how many people develop diabetes during 10 years when the data set includes info up to 25 years?

Tags: r, analysis, survival

I struggle with R ....How do I cut out the observations from 10- 25 years  to make a Kaplan meier plot for up to 10 years:

what would I add to this line of code?  Or would I Need to make separate groups for 0-1 year, 1-2 years and so on?

```
km.model <- survfit(Survival(Time, Diabetes) ~ Over40, type = "Kaplan-Meier")
plot(km.model, conf.int = F, lab = "Time(years)", lab = %Notdiabetic = S(t), main = "KM-Model")
```

Comment: Since you're plotting a `survfit` object, you can find the relevant plotting help page at `?plot.survfit`. There you'll see the argument `xlim` to set the x-axis limits, so add `xlim = c(0, 10)` to your plot call (assuming it is in years... `xlim = c(0, 10 * 365)` if your data is in days...)

Comment: Thanks Gregor- this was exactly what  I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

As with most base plotting functions, you can set the x-axis limits with `xlim`. See `?plot.survfit` for more details.

```
plot(
  km.model,
  conf.int = F,
  lab = "Time(years)",
  lab = "%Notdiabetic = S(t)",
  main = "KM-Model", 
  xlim = c(0, 10)
)
```